# How to parse date with time in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, nsdateformatter, ios7.1

I have dates in format e.g.

`2014-12-09T11:10:23.0000000-08:00`

How To parse this date & get `2014-12-09T11:10:23`.

Please Help I have tried with many date formatters in `setDateFormat:` method.

Comment: So many 0's.... it looks like multiple `SSSSSSS` are there. create new formatter without that may `S` and one `Z` and you will get it in string.

Comment: @Anoop Vaidya : Sory I didn't get You.

Comment: Is there a reason just taking the first 19 characters won't work?

Comment: @MarcusAdams: That wouldn't be good thing, as at times it may be 18 characters...

Comment: Did you try consulting [THE DOCUMENTATION](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)??

Comment: @MarcusAdams: may be he get month and date without 0-prefix.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya, that's a rather standard format. Dates will be zero padded. Could convert, but since just throwing away fractional seconds and time zone designator and the end result is a string, just taking first 19 characters should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZZZZZ"`

(It's all in [the spec](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) if you bother to look.)

Comment: so after this he again need to use another formatter to convert it to his required format, isn't it?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya - Yes, and that's in the spec too.